# Xsd ограничение значения в атрибуте

Tags: регулярные-выражения, xml, xsd

Подскажите, как сделать ограничение на значение атрибутов в схеме xml

Необходимо запретить значение атрибута 0, в том числе 0.0, но разрешить любое другое текстовое значение.

Пытаюсь решить регулярным выражением в restriction base="xs:string" при помощи pattern, но данный элемент указывает какие символы разрешены, а не запрещены...

Можно ли составить регулярное выражение на запрет?

Comment: Нет простого способа с помощью регулярного выражения. Кстати, что насчёт `00`, `000`, `0.00`, `000.0000`?

Comment: Если не должны проходить только 2 значения, попробуйте `<xs:pattern value="([^0]|..|.{4,}|[^0]..|.[^.].|..[^0])" />`. Если пустая строка валидна, добавьте `?` после последней закрывающей скобки.

Comment: Да, в том числе повторяющиеся нули.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13773547/5045688 - так можно запретить нули (0, 00, 000 и т. д.).

Comment: Да, вопрос только как избежать совпадения в `0.00` и `00.00000`?

Comment: По сравнению с другими разновидностями регулярных выражений, разновидность схемы XML довольно ограничена в возможностях. Поскольку она используется только для проверки того, соответствует ли шаблон целому элементу или нет, т.е. описывается допустимый формат.

Comment: Вы можете использовать XmlSchema 1.1? В этой версии есть assertion, которые, вроде, позволяют реализовать нужную проверку.

Comment: Ну как, решили проблему?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew к сожалению нет. Не все тестовые числа проходят проверку. Пока в этом месте провал. В понедельник могу сказать более точно, если интересно, какие числа не прошли проверку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Не могу сказать точно. Проверка происходит при помощи MS VS 2013 при создании XML вручную. В последствие на уровне сервера проверяют XML средствами Powershell (c#), и отбраковываются XML не прошедшие проверку. На сколько понимаю, VS использует 1.0 формат схем.

Comment: Угу, в платформе .NET реализована только схема 1.0. Чтобы использовать 1.1, нужно подключать какие-нибудь сторонние библиотеки. Дизайнер Студии при этом не будет их использовать.